# How to pair up the vowels and consonants of a string into all possible way in a list?

Tags: python, list

For example:
string = "edaca"

```
output = ['ac', 'ad', 'ec', 'ed']
```

I've only managed to seperate the string in 2 lists of consist of vowels and consonants without duplicates.

```
v_list = ['e', 'a']
c_list = ['d', 'c']
```

But I'm not sure how to pair them up to ['ac', 'ad', 'ec', 'ed'].

```
def get_vowel_consonant_pairs(letters):
    v_list = [] 
    c_list = [] 
    result_list = []
    vowels = "aeiou"
    consonant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    for letter in letters:
        if letter not in v_list:
            if letter not in c_list:
                if letter in vowels:
                    v_list.append(letter)

                if letter in consonant:
                    c_list.append(letter)
```

Comment: Have you tried a double for loop, iterating over `v_list` and then `c_list` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using sets to find the intersection of letters and vowels and consonants, and then [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to find all the combinations:

```py
import itertools

def get_vowel_consonant_pairs(letters):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    consonants = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')
    letters = set(letters)
    v_list = vowels & letters
    c_list = consonants & letters
    return [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(v_list, c_list)]

get_vowel_consonant_pairs('edaca')
```

Output

```
['ac', 'ad', 'ec', 'ed']
```

If you don't want to use a library, you can use a list comprehension to put together the values:

```py
return [''.join([v, c]) for c in c_list for v in v_list]
```

Note (as pointed out by @MadPhysicist) if `letters` can only contain letters, you don't need `consonants`, you can simply set

```py
c_list = letters - vowels
```

Comment: Technically you just need vowels: `s & vowels`, `s - vowels`

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right, if `letters` only contains letters, that will work. I've updated the answer with a note. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use

**loop**
like this.

```
for v in v_list:
  for c in c_list:
    result_list.append(f"{v}{c}")
```

Comment: This doesn't eliminate duplicates